# Facebook auth with pointer url

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, meteor, facebook-oauth

I have a domain name that points to an amazon instance. I am trying to get facebook authentication to work through my Facebook app. Unfortunately authentication through Facebook **only** works when a user goes directly to the url of the instance.

Ex: it works at my ec2-... url but not my domain url even though they share the same ip.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: *Unfortunately authentication through Facebook only works when a user goes directly to the url of the instance rather than the url that points to the instance.*  I'm afraid that doesn't exactly make sense, because "the URL of the instance" isn't really a concept that has a valid definition.  If a hostname points to an IP address, then hostname points to the IP address.  One hostname is not somehow more "the hostname" than another one.  Is your web server, perhaps, redirecting requests back to itself with a different hostname?

Comment: The amazon instance shares the IP address of the pointer hostname.

Comment: Right, but that shouldn't matter.  Vast numbers of web sites do not have a meaningful pointer record.

Comment: ok, the server isn't redirecting requests back to itself under a different hostname. Likely my lack of knowledge DNS is preventing me from seeing the solution to this issue.

Comment: … and so is the lack of any real useful data on our end. So tell us what the URL you are using is, so that we can have a look at how it “behaves,” DNS-wise …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem originated in the use of an incorrect environment variable url within my deployment script.